# Infragistics Clickable PieChart

Tags: .net, events, graph, infragistics, pie-chart

I am attempting to create a clickable piechart in ASP.NET 2.0 with C# using version 7.1 of Infragistics' software.

The chart appears as it should, but the function marked in the OnChartDataClicked event is not called.

From the .aspx:

<igchart:UltraChart ID="UltraChart1" runat="server" OnChartDataClicked="DataRegionClicked">

<PieChart></PieChart>

</igchart:UltraChart>

And in the .aspx.cs:

protected void DataRegionClicked(object sender, Infragistics.UltraChart.Shared.Events.ChartDataEventArgs e) {

Session["BLOCK"] = "some nearly random text";

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiddler revealed a 404 error on retrieval of one of the Infragistics js files.  Problem solved by copying the Infragistics directory structure directly into the project.